# Is this the correct way to send email with PHP?

Tags: php, email, encoding, utf-8

I'm a bit worried if this function sends emails that can be recognized correctly on the majority of email and webmail clients the way it should, specifically I'm most concerned about this doubts:

- Are the UTF-8 declarations and attachments well formed?
- Do I need to use quoted_printable_decode()? If yes, where?
- Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7 or 8 bits? I've always seen 7 but since I'm sending a UTF-8 encoded mail I'm not sure.
- Should I use mb_send_mail() or mail() is enough?

**EDIT: I don't know why but the code is not showing up correctly, I made it available @ http://gist.github.com/104818**

**EDIT 2: I'm aware of other alternatives (libraries) for email handling, but for the sake of my own curiosity and knowledge I just wish to know if this code is 100% good, or if it's buggy.**

```
function Email($name, $from, $to, $subject, $message, $bcc = null, $attachments = null)
{
    ini_set('SMTP', 'localhost');
    ini_set('sendmail_from', $from);

    $name = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $from = filter_var($from, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject = filter_var($subject, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $boundary = '_Boundary_' . md5(microtime(true) . mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX));

    $headers = array
    (
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="Mixed' . $boundary . '"',
        'Date: ' . date('r', time()),
        'From: "' . $name . '" <' . $from . '>',
        'Reply-To: "' . $name . '" <' . $from . '>',
        'Return-Path: "' . $name . '" <' . $from . '>',
        'X-Mailer: PHP ' . phpversion(),
        'X-Priority: 2',
        'X-MSMail-Priority: High',
        'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
    );

    if (is_null($to) === false)
    {
        if (is_array($to) === false)
        {
            $to = explode(',', $to);
        }

        foreach ($to as $key => $value)
        {
            $to[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        }

        $to = implode(', ', array_filter($to));
    }

    if (is_null($bcc) === false)
    {
        if (is_array($bcc) === false)
        {
            $bcc = explode(',', $bcc);
        }

        foreach ($bcc as $key => $value)
        {
            $bcc[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        }

        $headers[] = 'BCC: ' . implode(', ', array_filter($bcc));
    }

    if (is_null($attachments) === false)
    {
        settype($attachments, 'array');

        foreach ($attachments as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_file($value) === true)
            {
                $attachments[$key] = array
                (
                    '',
                    '--Mixed' . $boundary,
                    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . basename($value) . '"',
                    'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($value) . '"',
                    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64',
                    '',
                    trim(chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($value)))),
                );

                $attachments[$key] = implode("\n", $attachments[$key]);
            }

            else
            {
                unset($attachments[$key]);
            }
        }

        $attachments = implode("\n", $attachments) . "\n";
    }

    $message = array
    (
        'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.',
        '',
        '--Mixed' . $boundary,
        'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="Alt' . $boundary . '"',
        '',
        '--Alt' . $boundary,
        'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"',
        'Content-Disposition: inline',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit',
        '',
        trim(strip_tags($message, '<a>')),
        '',
        '--Alt' . $boundary,
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"',
        'Content-Disposition: inline',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit',
        '',
        trim($message),
        '',
        '--Alt' . $boundary . '--',
        $attachments,
        '--Mixed' . $boundary . '--',
    );

    if (@mail($to, stripslashes($subject), implode("\n", $message), implode("\n", $headers)) === true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While that should work, I would strongly recommend using a prebuilt Mail/SMTP class such as [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html). While I don't think the whole Zend Framework is the cat's pajamas, I do have a very good opinion of their mail handling code.

EDIT: I should also add that using a prebuilt Mail/SMTP class will abstract almost all of the complexity/structure of multi-part emails.

**Update 2009-05-06:** Answering your question directly.

> - Are the UTF-8 declarations and attachments well formed?

They look decent enough.

> - Do I need to use `quoted_printable_decode()`? If yes, where?

No. You would want to use `quoted_printable_decode()` only if you are decoding an email message. Not when you are encoding one. Should you use **`quoted_printable_encode()`**? I will discuss this next.

> - Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7 or 8 bits? I've always seen 7 but since I'm sending a UTF-8 encoded mail I'm not sure.

Only use 8bit encoding if you know that the destination SMTP server can support it. However, since you are passing your email off to the local MTA, I wouldn't recommend setting this value. The default value is 7bit encoding, but it has it's own set of restrictions: up to 998 octets per line of the code range 1-127 with CR and LF only allowed to appear as part of the CRLF line ending (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-2.7).

I would recommend you use the Quoted-Printable (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7) Content-Transfer-Encoding. Where you are calling `trim(strip_tags($message, '<a>'))` and `trim($message)` you will want to enclose those with `quoted_printable_encode(trim(...))`.

> - Should I use `mb_send_mail()` or `mail()` is enough?

If you know you are **not** going to be handling Multibyte messages (Japanese, Korean, Chinese, etc.) then `mail()` should suffice.

Now that I've answered your initial questions, let me tell you where some problems exist.

1. You are specifying that the Character set of your Plain Text and Html content parts are UTF-8, however it doesn't appear as you are actually ensuring that they really are UTF-8 encoded.
2. You are checking for `null` in `$to`, `$bcc`, `$attachments` before you further process them, however, you aren't doing anything when they may actually be `null`. So, if you happen to receive a `null` for `$to`, you don't process the variable, but you continue to send an email to `null`.

As of right now, that's all I am going to go into but I am still going to highly recommend a pre-built solution as they have had lots of users/time to work out bugs.

Comment: I agree, Zend_Mail has everything you need and more!  Use a library developed by many people, it usually has less errors in it.

Comment: "If you know you are not going to be handling Multibyte messages (Japanese, Korean, Chinese, etc.) then mail() should suffice." - What messages in other languages, such as German, French, Portuguese and Spanish? Does mail() still suffice?

Comment: It really comes down to Character Encoding. If you are using UTF-8 for your character encoding (HTTP GET/POST, database, etc.) using mail() will work just fine as it is single byte. UTF-16/UCS-2, on the other hand, are Multibyte, and would require the use of mb_send_mail().

Answer (score 17):

I'm all for rolling-your-own in most situations, but when it comes to mail I'd heartily recommend making it easier on yourself and using something like [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/) (in that order, for my money).

As a side-bonus (and assuming you specify reply-to, etc), you also have much less chance of being tagged as spam.

Comment: Hmm.. I've never heard of Swift Mailer, but after reading through the documentation, I'm going to have to start considering it instead of Zend_Mail. Thanks for the info. +1

Comment: Yes. I really could recommend PHPMailer! It did a great job many times for me.