# mail() header problem for html email

Tags: php, email, header

I am trying to write a error reporting feature for a website in php. I cannot get the headers right so that the email will display as html.

Here is the code:

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $page = $_POST['page'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $error = $_POST['error'];

    $message  =  "<html><body> \n";   
    $message .=  "Email: $email \n";
    $message .=  "Page: $page \n";
    $message .=  "OS/ Browser: $browser \n";
    $message .=  "Error: $error \n";
    $message .=  "</body></html> \n";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' . '\r\n';
    $headers .= 'From:  <code@website.com>' . '\r\n';
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: $email ' . '\r\n';
    $headers .= 'X-Priority: 1' . '\r\n';

    $subject  = "[ERROR REPORT] Page: " . $page;

    mail("myEmail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers );

    $mesg = "Thank you for your report!";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically repeating what I answered for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809924/is-this-the-correct-way-to-send-email-with-php/), I'm all for rolling-your-own in most situations, but when it comes to mail I'd heartily recommend making it easier on yourself and using something like [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/) (in that order, for my money).

As a side-bonus (and assuming you specify reply-to, etc), you also have much less chance of being tagged as spam.

EDIT: Maybe it's just the example you've used, but there's no actual HTML in your message. Why not just use plain text? And yes, I'd use one of the classes I suggest for plain text too.

Comment: The example I used doesnt use html in it but in reality I do have html in there.

Comment: Suspected as much, but was just making the point - not so much for you even, more 'cos increasingly people seem to default to html email when often there's no need.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm a fan of Pear Mail (http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) and Pear Mail_Mime (http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime).

Sending an HTML e-mail (with a plain-text body, for clients that don't support HTML) is as simple as this:

```
include_once('Mail.php');
include_once('Mail/Mime.php');

$htmlBody = '<html><body><b>Hello World</b></body></html>';
$plainBody = 'Your client doesn\'t support HTML';
$em = Mail::factory('sendmail');
$headers = array('From'=>'me@domain.com', 'To'=>'joe@schmoe.com', 'Subject'=>'Cool Email');
$mime = new Mail_Mime();
$mime->setTxtBody($plainBody);
$mime->setHtmlBody($htmlBody);
$message = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$mail = $em->send('joe@schmoe.com', $headers, $message);
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem I noticed is that you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes in the proper places.

Use: `"\r\n"`

Instead of: `'\r\n'`