# Specify smtp server for php mail() in freebsd?

Tags: php, apache, smtp, email, freebsd

I have two dedicated servers, one of which is configured for sending email out (SPF, DKIM, other domain whitelisting methods, etc). I need to send email from both servers, but I want to send mail from both servers through the server that's been set up for it.

It doesn't look like I can explicitly set an SMTP server directly in the mail function. Is there a way I can override the value set in php.ini, through .htaccess or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend not using the `mail` command and using a pre-built PHP mailing solution. There are 2 great recommendations at the following: [Is this the correct way to send email with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809924/is-this-the-correct-way-to-send-email-with-php/809995#809995)

In using a pre-built solution, you can have all of your mail go to the same server if you choose.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how do these prebuilt mailing solutions get their mail delivered? direct socket connections? i would imagine they're not just wrappers for mail()....

Comment: With the ones I've used, you have your choice of transport. SMTP, which leverages PHP's socket functions, or Mail which leverages the underlying mail() command. I strongly recommend using the SMTP transport type because, if you were not aware of this, the mail() command can rewrite your email's FROM header to be that of the user the server is running as. E.g. User is Apache, Domain is yourdomain.com, Servername is www, it would change it to apache@www.yourdomain.com. SMTP doesn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [ezcMail](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/Mail) for sending emails. It has a clean object oriented prebuilt mailing package which is highly configurable.

Comment: as an update, i did indeed use ezcMail as my solution. it works great.