# Problem encoding with utf-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I referred to [serhio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128843/php-and-russian-letters?answertab=votes#tab-top) for the utf-8 encoding problem and hv been trying for the whole day different methods searched from net :( I want to show the chinese characters in subject lines but when received in gmail it shows rubbish characters. I had tried to put

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

on top of page but not working

i tried to add "\r\n" also not working

My code as below

```
$mail->charset = 'utf-8';
$mail->body('',$strInv);
$mail->subject('"=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode(我的问题)."?=" #'.$inquiry_no);
```

when I received in gmail subject looks like this :
"=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode(è®¢å •ç¡®è®¤)."?=" #00016

I really appreciate anyone can help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

when you fix it your subject string should look like this:

```
=?UTF-8?B?RUSSIANNNN?=
```

use the echo function to debug your subject string before you call
$mail->subject

or just do

```
$ssubject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode('RUSSIAN') . '?=';
$ssubject = $ssubject . $inquiry_no;
$mail->subject($ssubject);
```

good luck newbie

Comment: Hi marinara that you very much for your help, i tried your second suggestion and it works great. I hv been sit in front of pc since morning till evening for this problem... Thanks again...