# Create a file with another languages characters in php

Tags: php, file

i'm trying to create a file with name "`Дискография`" but in the folder appears with the name `Ð”Ð¸ÑÐºÐ¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ñ„Ð¸Ñ`.

The php file is in UTF-8.
I'm working on windows.
My file system is NTFS.

i have this:

```
<?php

    $nombre = "Дискография";
    $fp = fopen("C:/$nombre", 'w+');
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: good read http://evertpot.com/filesystem-encoding-and-php/

Comment: What file system do you have?

Comment: Have you tried using `base64_encode()` as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128843/php-and-russian-letters ?

Comment: In that case: [Unicode issue with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11118990/53114)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was addressed somewhat in another answer:
[How do I use filesystem functions in PHP, using UTF-8 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525830/how-do-i-use-filesystem-functions-in-php-using-utf-8-strings)

Original/old answer:

It probably depends on the coding of your filesystem, but at a guess, I'd use:

```
    $nombre = utf8_encode("Дискография");
```

Comment: ISO 8859-1 doesn’t contain the mentioned characters and the file is already in encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: I already tried with all this charsets but still not working   charset=koi8-r
 charset=windows-1251
 charset=cp866
 charset=iso-8859-5

Comment: this was the name i got whit urlencode: %D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: I ran a test but since I'm not running Windows, your code worked on without a problem. I originally suggested the encoding to ISO-8859-1 for Windows, but I didn't realise those characters weren't in it.

Comment: i got this with utf8_encode: ÃÂ”ÃÂ¸Ã‘ÂÃÂºÃÂ¾ÃÂ³Ã‘Â€ÃÂ°Ã‘Â„ÃÂ¸Ã‘Â

Comment: Follow the link posted above; the other question details better solutions.