# Best way to send attachment mail with out using SMTP classes in PHP

Tags: php, email

can any one please advice me to send attachment mail with out using SMTP classes in PHP

Comment: Any reason not to use SMTP class?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)** which has great options other than attachments.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php). I personally find this very hard so I suggest you take a look at phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that sends attachments via `mail()`, it has some flaws specially with encoding headers but you can learn how it's done and improve it if you like - check [this question for the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809924/is-this-the-correct-way-to-send-email-with-php).

I'd also like to add that **SwiftMailer** is an excellent PHP library to send emails, and you should favor it if you can over other custom implementations since it has continuous developments and fewer bugs.