# How do I format email headers

Tags: html, phpt

How do I format the information so when it's displayed in the Email client, it'll show line breaks and other html tags that' i've set in the .php file?

```
  //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);
```

would it be something like:

```
$message = '<b>$user_Message';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this the correct way to send email with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809924/is-this-the-correct-way-to-send-email-with-php)

Comment: You can not edit Header like that (refer below link) : [Send Email with Php with Formating](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)